# Now there are two sites: rus.SE and russian.SE. Shall the scope of this site be changed?

Tags: discussion

The sites are [not going to be merged](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2/1111). That answer proposes this site (russian.stackexchange.com) for foreigners learning Russian while the migrated site be for native speakers discussing aspects of the language, like with EL&U and ULL.

Shall this site be renamed to RLL - Russian Language Learning?

Comment: Or may be it can be "questions about Russian language in Russian" and "questions about Russian language in English"?

Comment: I'm very surprised that this site would become a site for learners. Is it currently a site for learners and not for native speakers? I can't tell from the content since I don't speak Russian, but http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic says that the site is “for people who are interested in studying or teaching Russian as well as for enthusiast and curious native speakers”, and I see a healthy amount of questions in Russians on the front page.

Comment: Ну вот блин!  А я что, неправильным сайтом всё это время пользовался?!

Comment: @cnst, Продолжай пользоваться обеими сайтами, только здесь пиши по-английски, а на rus - по-русски.

Comment: All tags on russian.stackexchange.com should be renamed back to english.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree. Scopes don't change because a new site is born, so I don't think ours should.

ELL was born with the specific purpose of addressing very basic questions being asked on EL&U. This site was born for being the site for learning Russian and also for discussing basic and non-basic questions.

You can still ask "finer point of the language" questions on here, they are not off topic. I'm also not particularly happy of restricting the language to English only, but I can see the rationale behind it and I understand its merits.

So, questions of any levels are still accepted on this site (with proper research shown in the question).

Answer (score 1):

I'm both hands for keeping the Russian site (rus) for Russian speakers, with Russian as a working language, and the English site (russian) for English speakers, regardless of their Russian level, with English as a working language.

My greatest challenge with learning new languages is inability to comprehend the native forum threads about some language subtlety, because I, first, don't always command over the language well enough to understand the answer itself, and, second, people answering in their own language tend to not keep in mind that the foreigners might be reading them, take understanding of the language for granted and fail to explain things that might seem obvious to them.

This is perfectly normal for a language forum in the language itself, but this might scare the potential learners away.

If we stick to English as a working language (one in which questions are asked and the answers are given) this could become a great resource for non-native speakers interested in Russian.

We don't place any additional restrictions on the questions and answers on top of those already in the FAQ, except that we require that both questions and answers are in English.

If there is a question in Russian, we just move it to rus.se

As for the name of the site, I think something like "Russian for non-native speakers" would do alright.